# Weights aren't mirroring

Tags: weight-painting, mirror, vertex-groups

I seem to be having an issue with mirroring weights (again). I have X Mirror enabled, painted one side, gone to Data > Vertex Groups > and selected Copy Vertex Group and even Mirror Vertex Group, and even if I rename the copy so it's something.L and something.R, it keeps putting the mirrored version over the top of the one that's already there. What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: Once the upload feature works correctly, I'll upload my save. It just keeps telling me 'error uploading'.

Comment: Nope. Can't upload my save, unfortunately. I just keep getting 'error uploading'. :(

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it helps to remind that X-mirror works along the x-axis. Your character would need to face negative Y to take advantage of that. And Object>Apply>Rotation also.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I’ll try that and see.

Comment: Okay, something still isn't right. I wish I could upload a save... :-\ From what it looks like to me, the model is facing negative Y anyway, but it still isn't working. If I adjust the rotation on the Y axis however, the character rotates around clockwise/anti-clockwise from the centre of the grid. Rotating on the Z axis spins him around so he either faces towards the screen or has his back to it.